# How do I condition the use of certain assets to road groups in a Laravel project with Vite?

Tags: php, laravel, sass, vite, laravel-10

I have a Laravel 10 project using Vite.
I succeed in compiling assets with this configuration :

vite.config.js

```
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

var config = {
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app/appMaster.scss', 
                'resources/sass/admin/adminMaster.scss',
                'resources/sass/errors/errorsMaster.scss', 
                'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,

        }),
    ],
    build: {
        assetsDir: '',
    },
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    }

}

export default defineConfig(({command, mode, ssrBuild}) => {
    if (command === 'serve') {
        config.publicDir = 'public';
        config.build = {
            assetsDir: '',
            copyPublicDir: false,
            emptyOutDir: true,
        };
    }

    return config;
});
```

layout.blade.php

```
[...]
@vite(['resources/sass/app/appMaster.scss', 'resources/sass/admin/adminMaster.scss', 'resources/sass/errors/errorsMaster.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
[...]
```

As you can see my scss is split into three files.
I have some routes groups and I don't want for example the adminMaster.scss to be used in app route group.

With laravel mix in an older project I'm using some middlewares to compiling assets according to the route group.

How can I do that with Vite?

I'm wondering if I have to make a different configuration because I understand that with        `@vite(['resources/sass/app/appMaster.scss', 'resources/sass/admin/adminMaster.scss', 'resources/sass/errors/errorsMaster.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])` all scss files are loading and can't be conditioned.

Is anyone already did it or have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar situation, although I am trying to conditionally load Js based on the user being authenticated or not. I had to build the logic right into the `@vite()` helper.